# How to make Prettier not format my Liquid code inside of an HTML file

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, liquid, prettier

I am writing html files with liquid code in VS Code. When Prettier auto-formats inside the .html file, I'd like it to respect the liquid code and not break tags and objects across lines. I have downloaded the shopify/prettier-plugin-liquid extension per some other documentation, but I honestly don't even know how to use it or set it up. perhaps I couldn't find the correct documentation. Can anyone provide guidance on how to set this up or if a different approach will work better?

I tried installing the shopify/prettier-plugin-liquid plug-in, but I don't think I've set it up correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.